# How to detect the index path in collection view

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, indexpath

Let's see. I have collection view. I need to detect the index path of some element from datasource that still didn't load in cellForItemAt indexPath. I need it to scroll collection view to specific element that I want. The datasource includes sections by date and it could be very long. How can I detect it?

Comment: The answer is there in your question. _"I need to detect the index path of some element from **datasource** "_

Comment: ok, I think I got it...